Can I use symbolic link to .gitlab-ci.yml?
Now my project looks like this
/ProjectRoot
  - .gitlab-ci.yml (symbolic link to "shared/.gitlab-ci.yml")
  - shared (this is submodule)
    - .gitlab-ci.yml

In this situation, pipeline fails because of "yaml invalid".
When I open ".gitlab-ci.yml" file at gitlab, the content of that file is "shared/.gitlab-ci.yml"
Is there any solution that I can use symbolic link to ".gitlab-ci.yml" and link it to the file in submodule ?
I wanna use same ".gitlab-ci.yml" file in multiple projects.
Thanks.
In pileline editor, the content of ".gitlab-ci.yml" file is "shared/.gitlab-ci.yml"

I wanna use same ".gitlab-ci.yml" file in multiple projects. then do that


Is there any solution that I can use symbolic link to ".gitlab-ci.yml" and link it to the file in submodule ?

No.

I wanna use same ".gitlab-ci.yml" file in multiple projects.

So include: one .gitlab-ci in another, see for example https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/01/03/keeping-your-development-dry/ .
You would use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#includeproject .
